# jQuery and Array isArray are not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery and Array `isArray` are not working correctly

If I do:

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

jQuery.isArray(tags) // returns false
Array.isArray(tags)  // returns false

function isArray(object){
  return typeof object === "object" && object.length > -1;
}

isArray(tags) // return true
```

This issue causes an actual bug on my website:

On my website I have a form tag with inputs name "plan".

If I only have one input name "plan", it will return an none array.

But if I have two inputs and both have name "plan", it will return an array.

I used `jQuery.isArray` to check if it's an array or not but was forced to abandon using jQuery isArray.

People commented that it's nodelist but the usage of nodelist is exactly like an array. So under what circumstances you would actually want to avoid it to use like an array?

Comment: It depends.  How do you define "array"? `tags` _isn't_ an `Array`.

Comment: If they both return false, chances are they got it right, and you're wrong, and it's not really an array.

Comment: @adeneo: Specifically, it's a NodeList.

Comment: @SLaks - Indeed, and it's even "live" !

Comment: but the usage of the returned value is exactly like an array, and you traverse it just like an array. Why would you want it to return a false value?

Comment: But it's not an array, it's a nodeList, which is almost like an array, but it's really not, it's a collection of DOM nodes in a list, a nodeList.

Comment: @ChihungYu: Because the whole point of those functions is to check whether it's a _real_ `Array`, not an "array-like" object.

Comment: @SLaks: Exactly!  It even says that in the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.isarray/ :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's working correctly. `getElementsByTagName` returns a nodelist - an array-LIKE object but not an actual array, so jQuery is right to return false.

Your function is returning true because it is testing for the type being an object (a nodelist is an object) and it having a length (a nodelist has a length).

If you truly want to test for an array use `foo instanceof Array`.